# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R}\frac{n \log^{4}(x)}{n+nx+x^2}\chi_{[0,\infty[}d\lambda(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R}\frac{n \log^{4}(x)}{n+nx+x^2}\chi_{[0,\infty[}d\lambda(x)$

This seems like an apt situation to utilize dominating convergence.

$f_{n}(x):=\frac{n \log^{4}(x)}{n+nx+x^2}$ is continuous on $]0,\infty[$ and therefore measurable $\forall n \in \mathbb N$. But I am struggling to show $\int_{[0,\infty[}\frac{n \log^{4}(x)}{n+nx+x^2}d\lambda(x)=\int_{]0,\infty[}\frac{n \log^{4}(x)}{n+nx+x^2}d\lambda(x)<\infty$ to ensure $(f_{n})_{n}\subseteq\mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu)$.

$|\frac{n \log^{4}(x)}{n+nx+x^2}|\leq...?$

Any hints?

Comment: Hint: The integrand monotone-increases to $(\log x)^4/(1+x) \mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Is there a reason why you repeatedly use, for various functions $g$, the incorrect formula $$\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)\chi_{[0,\infty[}d\lambda(x)$$ rather than the correct $$\int_0^\infty g(x)dx\ ?$$

Comment: I was of the view $\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)\chi_{[0,\infty[}d\lambda(x)=\int_{[0,\infty[}g(x)d\lambda(x)$ as the lebesgue integral rather than $\int^{\infty}_{0}g(x)dx$ which we defined as the Riemann integral

Comment: using Fatou's lemma you can see that the limit diverges to infinity

Comment: @Masacroso I am stuck on the estimate to pick

Comment: @SABOY Fatou's lemma doesnt need an estimate... we have that for a sequence of measurable functions $(f_n)$ in a measure space $(X,\mu,\overline{\Bbb R}^+)$ then it ever holds that $$\int_X \varliminf_n f_n\,d\mu\le\varliminf_n\int_X f_n\, d\mu,\qquad\text{ in }\overline{\Bbb R}^+$$ where $\varliminf$ is the limit inferior. In this case the normal limit coincides with the limit inferior

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've got one more question: In our definition of Fatou's Lemma, we have included that there must be a $g \in \bar{\mathcal{L^{1}}}$ such that $g \leq f_{n}, \forall n \in \mathbb N$. I do not quite get the point of this $g$, seems rather futile. But knowing mathematics, I know there is a reason. Could you explain?

Comment: maybe you mean that you are searching an estimate for the integral $\int_{[0,\infty)}\frac{(\log x)^4}{1+x}\,\lambda(dx)$? You have one in the answer of @p4sch, just fill the details, find a rough estimation of the integral in the set $[0,e]$, just note that the integrand is positive and that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{(\log x)^4}{1+x}=\infty$, at least the integral is positive here

Comment: @SABOY I dont know your version of Fatou's lemma, I just know the version of above. Probably your version of Fatou's lemma is extended to a measure space $(X,\mu,\overline{\Bbb R})$ instead of $(X,\mu,\overline{\Bbb R}^+)$. In this case the condition $g\le f_n$ seems to be added to ensure that, by the dominated convergence theorem, the integral $\lim_n\int_X f_n^-\,d\mu=\int_X\lim f_n^-\, d\mu$, where $f_n^-$ is the negative part of $f_n$. Anyway Im just guessing, Idk really the reasons on your version of Fatou's lemma. In you case you can choose $g=0$

Comment: If you insist on using overcharged notations for no valid reason, at least use $$\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)\chi_{[0,\infty[}(x)d\lambda(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $x > 0$ we have
$$f_n(x):= \frac{\log(x)^4}{1+x+x^2/n}.$$
Thus for all $x >0$
$$f_n(x) \le f_{n+1}(x) \le f(x):=\frac{\log(x)^4}{1+x}$$
and pointwise $f_n \rightarrow f$. Therefore, we can apply the monotone convergence theorem. However, the limes $f$ is not integrable, because
$$\int_{e}^\infty f(x) \, dx  \ge \int_{e}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x} \, dx =\infty,$$
and we cannot apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

To apply LDCT you need an $L^1$ majorant $g$ satisfying $|f_n(x)| \le g(x)$ almost everywhere for all $n$. If $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere then you  have $|f(x)| \le g(x)$ too.

You can write $$f_n(x) = \frac{n \log^4 x}{n + nx + x^2} = \frac{\log^4 x}{1 + x + x^2/n}$$ so that $$f_n(x) \to \frac{\log^4 x}{1+x}.$$
This function is not integrable, so you won't find an integrable majorant $g$ with $|f_n| \le g$  for all $n$. It looks like LDCT may not be the way to go.